# Create popup with Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I am new to Clojurescript and trying to test basic functions -- in this case creating a popup.

This code displays the button:

```
            [:div {:class "dim-a item"}
             [dc :div {:dc-id 3 :hidden false}
              [:div {:class "item"
                     :style {:border        "1px solid #D4D4D4"
                             :border-radius "3px"}}
               [:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view" :style {:color "#555555"}}] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

This is what I tried to create the popup, but it does not compile.

```
            [:div {:class "dim-a item"}
             [dc :div {:dc-id 3 :hidden false}
              [:div {:class "item"
                     :style {:border        "1px solid #D4D4D4"
                             :border-radius "3px"}}
               [:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view" :style {:color "#555555" {:on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)}
                                                         [:div.alert.alert-info
                                                            [:div "Hello!"]]}}] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
When I try this:

```
            [:div {:class "dim-a item"}
             [dc :div {:dc-id 3 :hidden false}
              [:div {:class "item"
                     :style {:border        "1px solid #D4D4D4"
                             :border-radius "3px"}}
                 [:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view"
                                 :style {:color "#555555" {:on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)}}}
                        [:div.alert.alert-info
                          [:div "Hello!"]]] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

I get this:

```
------ ERROR -------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: /Users/reallymemorable/Documents/m/renderer.cljs:750:100
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 747 |                      :style {:border        "1px solid #D4D4D4"
 748 |                              :border-radius "3px"}}
 749 |                  [:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view"
 750 |                                  :style {:color "#555555" {:on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)}}}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
m/renderer.cljs [line 750, col 100] The map literal starting with :color on line 750 column 41 contains 3 form(s). Map literals must contain an even number of forms.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 751 |                         [:div.alert.alert-info
 752 |                           [:div "Hello!"]]] [:br] "Color"]]]]
 753 | 
 754 |             [:div {:class "dim-c"}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT #2:

I realize that I part of my difficulty was that the `on-click` code I had copied from another source had irrelevant details.  I've started over with a much simpler example.

```
[:div {:class "bp3-button"} [bp/icon {:icon "globe" :on-click "hello" :style {:color "#555555"}}]]
```

The above code compiles, but when I click the icon, nothing happens.  Sorry, I know this is a terrible way to get help with a question, but super new to Clojurescript and feeling my way through the darkness.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard without seeing the actual compilation error, or what the `bp` namespace is for (I'm guessing it's related to Bootstrap?), but if you fix the indentation a bit, I think it's the following:

You have this

```clj
[:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view"
                :style {:color "#555555" {:on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)}
                        [:div.alert.alert-info
                         [:div "Hello!"]]}}] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

Your `[:div.alert.alert-info` is misplaced as a child of `:style`. What I think you meant is:

```clj
[:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view"
                :style {:color "#555555" {:on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)}}}
       [:div.alert.alert-info
        [:div "Hello!"]]] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

**Edit**: Based on your output, the code probably needs to look like this instead:

```
[:div [bp/icon {:icon "grid-view"
                :on-click  #(reset! popup-shown false)
                :style {:color "#555555"}}
       [:div.alert.alert-info
        [:div "Hello!"]]] [:br] "Color"]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried your suggestion and edited my post to show what I tried and the resulting error.

Comment: OK, so if you look at the error, it says that the map that starts with `:color` is not well formed because one key-value pair is `:color` with `"#555555"`, but `{:on-click...` is in a position where it would be the key of a value that does not exist at the same level. Check my edit to the answer above and see if that works

Comment: I updated my question again in a way that will hopefully be a lot clearer.

Comment: In order to help you I need to know what the `bp` namespace is. What library does it come from?

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning everything backwards it seems.  I'm using the Blueprint components: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/

Comment: I'm trying to create what is called a "dialog" in the docs: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/dialog

Comment: I think you probably want to start with a smaller, basic working example before jumping into using a larger library. I know this might sound discouraging, but otherwise I will become very frustrating. If you are coming from the React side of things, my recommendation would be to check on https://shadow-cljs.org/ and build a small app that contains a button that logs a message to the console. Once you've moved past that point, build on top of that example to import more libraries.

Comment: I have an example project that uses Reagent, React and Fabric UI here: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/fabric-todos/ ... it still doesn't use Shadow CLJS to build (it would things more familiar) but I think you'll be able to follow what's going on and you can use it to explore, and maybe you can replace the relevant bits to use Blueprint instead of Fabric :-)

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve your original question, but I went ahead and created a small demo project in [this repo](https://github.com/dfuenzalida/blueprint-cljs) that renders a couple of buttons, one just prints on the console and the second shows an example dialog, just like in the screenshot below:

[image]

It should work with `yarn install ; yarn run html ; yarn run watch`.